# How can i save multiple checkbox value those are checked in cakephp hasMany relation?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Suppose I have 3 tables `property_details`, `property_feature_details`, `property_feature_relations`.

PropertyDetail Model has the hasMany relation with PropertyFeatureRelation.

AT the time saveing my data array looks like that:

```
$this->data = array('PropertyDetail' => array('name'=>'xyz'),'PropertyFeatureRelation' => array('0' => array('feature_id'=>1),'1' => array('feature_id'=>5),'2' => array('feature_id'=>0),'3' => array('feature_id'=>0)));
```

Those feature_ids values are coming out from the checkboxes. Those are checked they are contains ids value and non checked are having 0 value. But in the child table saves all the data zero and non zeros.

Actually I want to save those checkboxes values which are only checked. Please do not provide any manual controller logic. Help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am explaining you with my example which is having question ,answer and its survey

you can use multiple checkbox syntax as below:

```
                                             $answers=array();
                                    $tmp_ans=$question['Answer'];
                                    for($j=0;$j < count($tmp_ans);$j++)
                                    $answers[$tmp_ans[$j]['id']]=$tmp_ans[$j]['answer'];            
                                    echo '<li>';
                                        echo $this->Form->input('Answer', array(
                                        'type' => 'select',
                                        'name'=>'Answer['.$question['Question']['id'].']',
                                        'class'=>'test',
                                        'label'=>false,
                                        'multiple' => 'checkbox',
                                        'options' =>$answers ,
                                        ));

                                    echo '</li>';
```

after that you will have only those answers which you have checked others will not come in array of post so to save data you can use below syntax

```
if(!empty($this->data['Answer'])){

                foreach ($this->data['Answer'] as $key=>$val):

                    if(!empty($val)):
                            if(is_array($val)):

                                foreach ($val as $ans):
                                    $post_data['UserAnswer']['id']='';
                                    $post_data['UserAnswer']['survey_id']=$id;
                                    $post_data['UserAnswer']['user_id']=$this->Auth->user('id');
                                    $post_data['UserAnswer']['question_id']=$key;
                                    $post_data['UserAnswer']['answer_id']=$ans;
                                    $this->UserAnswer->save($post_data['UserAnswer']);
                                endforeach;
                            else:
                                    $post_data['UserAnswer']['id']='';
                                    $post_data['UserAnswer']['survey_id']=$id;
                                    $post_data['UserAnswer']['user_id']=$this->Auth->user('id');
                                    $post_data['UserAnswer']['question_id']=$key;
                                    $post_data['UserAnswer']['answer_id']=$val;
                                    $this->UserAnswer->save($post_data['UserAnswer']);

                            endif;

                    endif;
                endforeach;

            }
```